# Ranking tweets from most relevant to least relevant in a document using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tf-idf, topic-modeling

I have a document with, say, 15 tweets. Given a query, how can we rank the tweets from most relevant to the query to least relevant?

That is, let D be the document containing 15 tweets:

```
D = ['Tweet 1', 'Tweet 2' ..... 'Tweet 15']
Q = "some noun phrase"
```

Given Q, what method we can use for ranking the tweets from most relevant to least relevant?

All tweets are similar and belong to the same topic.
Can I use [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (it's a bad idea, I think), topic modelling?

Comment: What is "TFIDF"? [frequency–inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)? Please edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: Edited! Thank you!

Comment: The question is, really, "what is relevant and what is not". Once you know how to define that, then you can implement an algorithm. And defining that is entirely up to you. It is not really a python question, I would say.

Comment: Finally, I did somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yoe need [nltk](http://www.nltk.org") (Natural Language Toolkit) libery. There is built-in function which count tf-idf